# Is it possible to make a dynamic multidimensional-array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is it posible to make a dynamic multidimensional-array?

I would like to make a recursive function with arrays.
So it would be wonderful if i could say something like

```
$array['chapters'][$a]['subject'][$b] = array( "title" => (string) $item );
```

the next time - it would be like this

```
$array['chapters'][$a]['subject'][$b]['subject'][$c] = array( "title" => (string) $item );
```

and then,

```
$array['chapters'][$a]['subject'][$b]['subject'][$c]['subject'][$d] = array( "title" => (string) $item );
```

and,

```
$array['chapters'][$a]['subject'][$b]['subject'][$c]['subject'][$d]['subject'][$e] = array( "title" => (string) $item );
```

and,

so, is there any possibility for doing something like this?

```
$superArray = "$array['chapters'][$a]['subject'][$b]"
```

and the next time,

```
superArray += "['subject'][$c]"
```

??

All help is welcome.

---

The reason fot this all:
I'm making a recursive function from the next block of code, because it has always the same pattern:
+ I'm parsing a XML file into arrays's so that i can use it later in drupal

```
$resulty = $xpaths->xpath("/org.olat.course.Structure/rootNode/children/*[ident = '$item->ident']/children/*[type = 'st' or type = 'sp' or type = 'bc']");
if ($resulty > 0) {
foreach ($resulty as $itemy) {

  $x = 0;
  $array['chapters'][$s]['subject'][$d] = array(
    'id' => (string) $itemy->ident,
    'shortTitle' => (string) $itemy->shortTitle,
    'type' => (string) $itemy->type,
  );
  switch ($itemy->type) {
    case "bc":
      $course_map = getDirectoryList("/opt/olat/olatdata/bcroot/course/$course/foldernodes/$item->ident");
      for ($i = 0; count($course_map) > $i; $i++) {
        $location = "/opt/olat/olatdata/bcroot/course/$course/foldernodes/$item->ident/$course_map[$i]";
        $array['chapters'][$s]['subject'][$d]['files'][$x] = array(
          "name" => $course_map[$i],
          "location" => $location,
          "size" => format_bytes(filesize($location)),
          "type" => filetype($location),
          "modified" => date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($location))
        );
      }
      break;
    case "sp" || "st" :
      $resultz = $xpaths->xpath("//*[ident = '$itemy->ident']/moduleConfiguration/config//string[starts-with(.,'/')]");
      foreach ($resultz as $itemz) {
        $array['chapters'][$s]['subject'][$d] += array(
          "html-page" => (string) $itemz,
        );
      }
      break;
  }
                        <<<--- When you go deeper, than all this wil be set here

  $d++;
   $x++;
}
}
```

Comment: are a.b.c.d just key ints? looks like there are more efficient shapes for this data set.

Comment: so, is there any possibility for doing something like this? Well, did you do something like that?

Comment: Yes its possible, but why you need something like that ?

Comment: Have you thought of using objects and data structures for this? Seems more appropriate (though I don't know exactly what you're doing)

Comment: Yes, php will let you do that. Essentially you're making a tree here, so it might make more sense to just use a tree datastructure.

Comment: ">" is Markdown for quoting. To [format blocks of lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/), use only the four-space prefix. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Try editing your question and fix the markup (including the breaks in the first line of the long code sample). Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting. As for the first four samples, did you try them? There's no need to put "Edited" in the title or anywhere else.

Comment: I'm comming from a XML tree,
And I'm trying to parse the XML tree into Array, for using (in the future) Drupal

Comment: @DieterVerbeemen: There are libraries to parse XML into very comfortable objects and nodes, you should try them **[SimpleXML](http://il.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)** for instance.

Comment: Its possible but not efficient ... Just use XML xpath

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you mean, but if you want to keep track of your last "Super array" and add items to it you can do so by keeping track of reference ([&](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)) to the last super array.

```
$input = array($b, $c, $d, $e);
$result = array('chapters' => array($a => array()));
$current = &$result['chapters'][$a];

foreach ($input as $iter) {
    $current['subject'][$iter] = array( "title" => (string) $iter );
    $current = &$current['subject'][$iter];
}
```